# How to write data to a binary file using C

Tags: c

I want to write the CAN frames to binary file including the current timestamp and CAN ID followed by 8bytes data frame. I have following in my program,

```
fwrite("&tm->tm_mon+1", sizeof(tm->tm_mon+1),1,fptr);
fwrite("&tm->tm_mday", sizeof(tm->tm_mday+1),1,fptr);
fwrite("&tm->tm_hour", sizeof(tm->tm_hour+1),1,fptr);
fwrite("&tm->tm_sec", sizeof(tm->tm_sec+1),1,fptr);
fwrite("&frame_rd->can_id", sizeof(frame_rd->can_id),1,fptr);
fwrite("&frame_rd->data", sizeof(frame_rd->data),1,fptr);
```

Is it right way to do so? Can anyone help me in doing it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sizeof(tm->tm_mon+1)` is the size of an (int) expression. (which is the size of an int)

Comment: "*Is it right way to do so?*" no. Is it hard to find a usage example of `fwrite()`? Also make sure to learn what a *string constant* is in C.

Comment: You are writing `sizeof(tm->tm_mon+1)` bytes from a buffer containing the string `"&tm->tm_mon+1"` to the file.

Comment: Did you have read tutorial or other ressouce ? Because it seem you don't understand the difference between binary read/write and text read/write.

Comment: No I didnot... I will do it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few hints (not a complete solution):

The fact that `tm->tm_mon` is zero-based and thus requires `+1` to make sense as a month number jan...dec, does not mean that you must write `sizeof(tm->tm_mon+1)`.

In the same way, if you want to write its value and take its address, that does not mean you have to add 1. Think what you are doing: to *what* are you adding this 1??? (just as think about what you were taking the size of.)

And if you want to write this value, then do not mix a function like `printf` which requires a format string (the `f` meaning "print formatted") with `fwrite` (the `f` meaning File Write). Thus you don't provide a format string with what you want to write, you just provide the address of what needs to be written. And of course without any +1 (what would you be adding this 1 to?)

With these hints I hope you can find your answer. And remember, If nothing helps, Read the Manual!

Comment: How can I write my time(date+hours+min+sec) followed by frame id and followed by data. For example, the timestamp is of size 32 bits, ID is of size 16bits and data is of size 8bytes. Can I use single fwrite function to write all these ?Thanks in advance

Comment: Jenny, a time _stamp_ is not the same as a date-and-time. First look up the definition of the CAN bus timestamp, then think about how to generate it.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say not a real timestamp, but the time when the CAN bus frame has occurred.